# How do I make a CSS sprite that controls multiple background images for multiple DIV's?

Tags: xhtml, css, sprite, css-sprites

**Hello everyone!**

I have a website which is http://www.urbanelementz.ca ... It's currently in development.

*Please note that I'm quite familiar with CSS sprites and can make mouse-over/rollover sprites as well as static image sprites. I use about 7 or 8 major sprites on my website that control most of the images and multiple mouse-overs (such as the menu, etc).*

**My question:** I have about 8-10 DIV's that use background images. As of now, each div has it's own background-image. Either I'm missing something very simple or I'm just stumped because I can't seem to code it properly to work.

**My problem:** I know how to make the sprite, I know how to link to the sprite but when you use the "background-position: 0px 0px" option it will move the background image position in the DIV and not the background position on the image to show the proper sprite.

**You can view my CSS file here:** http://www.urbanelementz.ca/css/style.css
Note that it's not fully organized or optimized at the moment because I'm making changes.

Please take a look at the css sprites which are all located towards the bottom and have comments so you can see which ones they are.

**Am I missing something obvious? Maybe I'm sleep deprived. =0)**

If someone can point me to a tutorial or just paste the proper coding and description of how to do it, that would be great.

**Thanks so much!**

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code and markup within the answer. :) A http://jsfiddle.net example would also be helpful.

Comment: No problem. So once someone answers the question I need to post the findings? How exactly to I mark a question as answered when the time comes?

Comment: If you post the markup/styles, with possibly a working demo of the problem, then hopefully one or more will provide an answer, with potentially one of the questions answering the problem you're having. At that point, you can click the outlined arrow to the left of the most appropriate answer, which will mark the question as answered. You can also upvote as many answers as you see fit.

Comment: Ohh ok I see what your saying. Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I don't really have any markup or anything that can be put into practice quite yet. I have to describe the "problem" or "process" of what I'm trying to do to see if someone has a solution. I linked to my CSS file which has multiple rollover and regular image sprites (at the bottom) so people can get a visual of what I'm talking about but unfortunately I don't have any actual markup/code of what I'm trying to do since I have no idea how to do it. =0)

Comment: If you want to repeat your sprite vertically the part of the image has to span the entire height of the composites image. Entire width if horizontal. So therefor you can't use spites if you want to repeat both horizontally and vertically. Sprites work best is you don't want to repeat. Otherwise usage is limited. You need css3 to select a portion of the image you want to repeat, but browser support is limited.

Comment: @urbanelementz - How does this fiddle either demonstrate or not demonstrate what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/TFwdB/

Comment: @Jared Farrish - That's exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. It's about 90% of my problem. Please keep that fiddle online so I can refer to it when doing what I need to do. @Gerben - That's another issue which is background images that span either horizontal or vertical. I don't think I have any that span both. Just X or Y axis. I should be able to figure it out from here. If you can post the answer Jared I will select it. Thanks very much guys!

Comment: @urbanelementz - I posted it in an answer. What is the part that it didn't demonstrate?

Comment: @Jared - Well what happens if I have a div that is 500x500px and I have a 50x50px image that's on the sprite and I want it to show up only in the top right hand corner of the div. Then it will show the whole sprite and not just that small piece. It works great if the piece of the sprite is the same size as the div but if the piece of the sprite I want is smaller than the full size of the div then it wont work. Does that make sense? There's ways to work around it like adding color space to the div to make it the full size. Same goes for the X or Y axis repeating image? Am I missing something?

Comment: @urbanelementz - Hmmm. Yeah, I think the straight-forward answer would be to make the sprite itself compensate by leaving the surround area around the image blank. I wouldn't imagine this would make the file size too much larger, but I haven't tested that. Another option may be to compensate with a relative-positioned div contained within a wrapper div to the other content you have, so that you can make the div with your sprite sized properly.

Comment: @Jared - OK great. I thought I was going crazy and just missing something really obvious. I needed someone else's input so thanks a lot. I think if I position everything on the sprite jusssst right then it will work properly. I would rather combine 8 or 9 BG images into 1 bigger image and weigh the good from the bad. My site is very image heavy as graphics is a big part of my company. At first the site loaded terribly @ 12 or 13 seconds on cable internet to a site that loads quite fast, looks good and is now about 4-5 seconds of loading time w/ empty cache. How does it look and load for you?

Comment: @urbanelementz - It looks great and loads in about 1.5 seconds (I'm in Dallas on FiOS, 25m download). You might consider a loading script, where the site doesn't display until all of the images were preloaded. jQuery script examples are out there that would show you what I mean. That way, until the images are loaded, the user just sees a loading graphic, maybe with a loading progress meter.

Comment: @Jared - Yea that's a good call. I think it would look really good with a loading meter or something. I might consider that. Do you have any links to a Jquery script like that? If not, I'll search around.

Comment: @urbanelementz - [Here is one](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/), but there are many out there. Really, all you need to do is onDOMReady, hide your content, run your preload script (with optional loading graphic incremented as each image finishes), then once all are finished, show the content.

Comment: @Jared - I just looked up the "background-size" attribute at the link below. This would solve my problem would it not?

http://www.w3schools...ground-size.asp

Background-size look like it's supported by all browsers according to w3schools.com .... So this is what I would need to make this work. Correct?

Comment: @Jared - Actually, Maybe background-size isn't what I want because that would just compress or stretch the full sprite, not contain the image to that specific size. (If that makes any sense). lol.

Comment: @urbanelementz - That's a CSS3 property, I believe, which would mean that IE support is questionable. I don't typically rely on w3schools, so at this link it tends to suggest that this property is not universally supported for IE browsers <9. http://caniuse.com/#search=Background-size

Comment: @Jared - OK that makes sense. I guess my best bet is to stay away from that property this until it's fully supported.

Comment: @urbanelementz - I wouldn't be relying on CSS3 properties just yet. At the moment, I'm watching The Big Lebowski (probably the greatest movie ever). I hope you fully support me focusing my attention on the dude and Walter.

Comment: Haha I sure do buddy. Thanks again. I hope to see you around! Take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, below is the content of the fiddle I created:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-image: url('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG');
}
#one {
  background-position: -15px 0;
}
#two {
  background-position: -15px -27px;
}
#three {
  background-position: -15px -54px;
}
#four {
  background-position: -15px -81px;
}
#five {
  background-position: -15px -108px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TFwdB/